# is there any way to get ether/ip headers via gen_tcp?

Tags: tcp, header, erlang, ethernet, gen-tcp

is there any way to get not only body of incoming message. but also `ether/IP` headers of it? Now i'm using `gen_tcp` and receive messages by active controlling process.

for now socket is opened via 'of_driver' in such way:

```
gen_tcp:connect(IpAddr, Port,  [binary, {packet, raw}, {active, false}],CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't get Ethernet or IP headers through `gen_tcp`.  You could use [the procket library](https://github.com/msantos/procket) to open a raw socket.  (The `{packet, raw}` option passed to `gen_tcp` doesn't refer to a "raw" socket; it just means that `gen_tcp` doesn't try to interpret the TCP byte stream to split it into packets.)